# Browser flashes white when resizing window using css media queries in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries

When resizing the browser window in Chrome, I'm getting a white flash when using a single CSS media query declaration. If I remove the media query, the problem goes away. Has anyone experienced this issue? Is there a workaround?

My media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    /* Styles go here */

}
```

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of research and chatting with a couple other people, we were able to find a fix for this webkit bug. To fix the white flash, I was able to use these CSS declarations:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

I've also been told that this may also get around the webkit bug:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I applied these declarations to the body tag, but it may work differently for you, depending on your website.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is  a known issue in chrome. What version are you using. Seems this was fixed as per this this thread;

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373

Comment: I'm using Version 20.0.1132.57, which is the latest version. Thanks for that thread, I'll take some time to read thru it.

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen stuttering animations when resizing windows on a Windows OS.

Here's an [article](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-resize-windows-animation/) about it.

I would try to apply a class that universally shuts off all the transitions and animations, like [so](https://css-tricks.com/stop-animations-during-window-resizing/).